# Meteor Spacebars - Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, or null

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a function, which if there is one player in a game it returns true

```
   Template.gamePage.searching = function() {
        var game = GameCollection.findOne({current: true});
        if(game.players.length === 1) {
            return true
        }
    };
```

I would like to show the below text through spacebars if this searching function returns true:

```
        {{#if {{searching}}}}
            <h1>Searching for an opponent</h1>
            <div>
            {{> spinner}}
            </div>
        {{/if}}
```

I get the below error:

```
client/views/games/game_page.html:35: Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, or null
...>.             {{#if {{searching}}}}     ...
```

Comment: `{{#if {{searching}}}}` -> `{{#if searching}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
 {{#if searching}}
            <h1>Searching for an opponent</h1>
            <div>
              {{> spinner}}
            </div>
 {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{{#if searching}}
      <h1>Searching for an opponent</h1>
      <div>
         {{> spinner}}
      </div>
{{/if}}
```